# Invoke an AWS Lambda function only after an Amazon DynamoDB export to Amazon S3 is totally complete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS and cloud technology in general. So, please bear with me if the use case below is a trivial one.

Well, I have a table in Amazon DynamoDB which I am exporting to Amazon S3 using exportTableToPointInTime API (ExportsToS3) on a scheduled basis everyday at 6 AM. It is being done using an AWS Lambda function in this way -

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });
    const tableParams = {
        S3Bucket: '<s3-bucket-name>',
        TableArn: '<DynamoDB-Table-ARN>',
        ExportFormat: 'DYNAMODB_JSON'
    };

    await dynamodb.exportTableToPointInTime(tableParams).promise();
};
```

The CFT template of the AWS Lambda function takes care of creating lambda roles and policies, etc. along with scheduling using Cloudwatch events. This setup works and the table is exported to the target Amazon S3 bucket everyday at the scheduled time.

Now, the next thing I want is that after the export to Amazon S3 is complete, I should be able to invoke an another lambda function and pass the export status to that lambda function which does some processing with it.

The problem I am facing is that the above lambda function finishes execution almost immediately with the exportTableToPointInTime call returning status as IN_PROGRESS.

I tried capturing the response of the above call like -

```
const exportResponse = await dynamodb.exportTableToPointInTime(tableParams).promise();
console.log(exportResponse);
```

Output of this is -

```
{
    "ExportDescription": {
        "ExportArn": "****",
        "ExportStatus": "IN_PROGRESS",
        "StartTime": "2021-09-20T16:51:52.147000+05:30",
        "TableArn": "****",
        "TableId": "****",
        "ExportTime": "2021-09-20T16:51:52.147000+05:30",
        "ClientToken": "****",
        "S3Bucket": "****",
        "S3SseAlgorithm": "AES256",
        "ExportFormat": "DYNAMODB_JSON"
    }
}
```

I am just obfuscating some values in the log with ****

As can be seen, the exportTableToPointInTime API call does not wait for the table to be exported completely. If it would have, it would have returned ExportStatus as either COMPLETED or FAILED.

Is there a way I can design the above use case to achieve my requirement - invoking an another lambda function **only** when the export is **actually complete**?

As of now, I have tried a brute force way to do it and which works but it definitely seems to be inefficient as it puts in a sleep there and also the lambda function is running for the entire duration of the export leading to cost impacts.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });
    const tableParams = {
        S3Bucket: '<s3-bucket-name>',
        TableArn: '<DynamoDB-Table-ARN>',
        ExportFormat: 'DYNAMODB_JSON'
    };

    const exportResponse = await dynamodb.exportTableToPointInTime(tableParams).promise();

    const exportArn = exportResponse.ExportDescription.ExportArn;
    let exportStatus = exportResponse.ExportDescription.ExportStatus;
    
    const sleep = (waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTimeInMs));
    
    do {
        await sleep(60000); //waiting every 1 min and then calling listExports API
        const listExports = await dynamodb.listExports().promise();
        const filteredExports = listExports.ExportSummaries.filter(e => e.ExportArn == exportArn);
        const currentExport = filteredExports[0];
        exportStatus = currentExport.ExportStatus;
    }
    while (exportStatus == 'IN_PROGRESS');

    var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
    var paramsForInvocation = {
        FunctionName: 'another-lambda-function',
        InvocationType: 'Event',
        Payload: JSON.stringify({ 'ExportStatus': exportStatus })
    };

    await lambda.invoke(paramsForInvocation).promise();
};
```

What can be done to better it or the above solution is okay?

Thanks!!

Comment: You could have your second Lambda function triggered by an S3 event like in [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)? The S3 event will only fire when the creation of the S3 file has finished

Comment: What if the exports to s3 API fails due to some reason? I guess it wont create the S3 file in that case, right?

Answer (score 3):

Context: we want to export the DynamoDB table `content` into an S3 bucket and trigger a lambda when the export is complete.

In CloudTrail there's an `ExportTableToPointInTime` event that is sent when the export is **started**, but no event for when the export is finished.

A way to trigger a lambda once the export is completed is by creating an S3 trigger using this configuration:
[image]

In particular:

- The creation event type is a complete multi-upload (others do not seem to work, not sure why).
- I think the prefix can be omitted, but it's useful. It's composed of:

  - The first part is the table name, `content`.
  - The second part, `AWSDynamoDB`, is set automatically by the export tool.
- This is the most important part. The last files created once the export is complete are `manifest-summary.json` and `manifest-summary.md5`. We must set the suffix as one of these files.

Answer (score 2):

One option to achieve this is to define a waiter in order to wait till a "Completed" status is returned from `exportTableToPointInTime`.

As far I can see there are a few default Waiters for DynamoDB already present, but there is not one for the export, so you'll need to write your own ([you can use those already present as an example](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/master/boto3/data/dynamodb/2012-08-10/resources-1.json)).

A good post describing how to use and write a waiter [could be found here](https://www.2ndwatch.com/blog/use-waiters-boto3-write/).

This way if the export takes less than 15 minutes you'll be able to catch it within the Lambda limits without the need of a secondary lambda.

If it takes longer than that, you'll need to decouple it, where you have multiple options as suggested by @Schepo and @wahmd:

- using an S3 event on the other end
- Using AWS EventBridge
- Using SNS
- combinations of the above.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and see how it goes. As I said, I am quite new to AWS. That said, this approach will still result in lambda execution costs until the export is totally complete, right?

Comment: That's correct, but it should be a bit clearer and a bit faster than having a sleep like you do at the moment. In your case you are just waiting for x amount of time, while in this case you are going to poll the API every Y seconds till you see a SUCCESS.

Answer (score 1):

For an await call, you are missing "async" keyword on handler.
Change

```
exports.handler = (event) => {
```

to

```
exports.handler = async event => {
```

Since this is an await call, you need 'async' keyword with it.

Let me know if it fixed your issue.

Also, I suspect you don't need `.promise()` as it might be already returning promise. Anyways, please try with & without it incase it still doesn't work.

After dynamoDB await call, You can invoke another lambda. It would make sure that your lambda is invoked after dynamoDb export call is completed.

To invoke second lambda,

- you can use aws sdk invoke package.
- putEvent api using eventBridge.

Later option is better as it decouples both lambdas & also, first lambda does not have to wait until the seconds invocation is completed. (reduces lambda time, hence reduces cost)

Comment: I wrongly mentioned without async in the question. The actual code has async on the handler already. Trying without .promise() on exportTableToPointInTime API call actually does not trigger the export at all.