# How can I wait for the export to complete using ExportTableToPointInTimeRequest?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I have used ExportTableToPointInTimeRequest api to export a dynamodb table to S3 in Java. I wanted to process the next steps only when the export is completed because there is also a glue job associated which will read the data from the s3 export. What can I do so that the code waits for a certain time before processing the next steps?

```
ExportTableToPointInTimeRequest exportTableToPointInTimeRequest = new ExportTableToPointInTimeRequest()
        .withTableArn(tableArn)
        .withS3Bucket(s3Bucket)
        .withExportFormat(ExportFormat.DYNAMODB_JSON)
        .withS3Prefix(s3Prefix);

ExportTableToPointInTimeResult exportTableToPointInTimeResult =
        dynamoDB.exportTableToPointInTime(exportTableToPointInTimeRequest);
```

---Process next steps---

Answer (score 1):

You don’t want to wait in the code for the export to complete.

Try EventBridge. Configure your Event Bus with a Rule that watches for events indicating that the S3 object containing the export has arrived, or that the export has completed. Then associate a target with that rule so that your Glue job kicks off when the event (the export completing) has happened.

This question has some answers with links and hints relating to this solution: [Invoke an AWS Lambda function only after an Amazon DynamoDB export to Amazon S3 is totally complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69259019/invoke-an-aws-lambda-function-only-after-an-amazon-dynamodb-export-to-amazon-s3).

I would favor the answers there suggesting an event-based solution, rather than the answers relating to waiting within the Lambda Function.

If you wait within your code, you have to manage the watching and waiting. AWS can handle the watching and waiting for you, all without charging you for the compute resources.